# Website with Java algorithms embedded into the site

Tags: java, html

Hi I want to create a small web application which will take inputs such as 80 and 120 and return the GCD of those numbers. I want to write the logic in Java. When the user enters 80 and 120 and clicks on calculate button, the values must be passed to the algorithm and return the answer to be displayed on the application again. How do I link the java algorithm to the html page in order to achieve this? Kindly suggest. Is there no other way of doing this other than creating a Java applet for this and deploying it on the application? Kindly help.

Comment: Are you sure you mean Java, and not JavaScript?

Comment: Hi. yea I would like to do this in Java because Im thinking of implementing some serious algorithms and not just GCD

Comment: depending on what Java features you need, you may have a look at Google Web Toolkit which is essentially a Java-to-JavaScript compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Applets" if you want the Java code to run in the users browser and not on a remote server.

Applets are, however, a waning technology due to the numerous attacks that has gone through the JVM to avoid the security checks in the browser, so your users will most likely not see the experience you want them to.  Additionally I believe that the ability for the Java program to interact with its surrounding page has been crippled again for security reasons.

Your best bet is to use Java for server side code only (which it is quite fine for - Google Application Engine is perhaps the easiest way to get started) and to use JavaScript for client side code.